# Leaking memory in detectMultiScale when detecting faces

Tags: ios, opencv, image-processing

I'm using the following function (successfully) to detect faces using OpenCV in iOS, but it seems to leak 4-5Mb of memory every second according to Instruments.

The function is called from processFrame() regularly.

By a process of elimination it's the line that called detectMultiScale on the face_cascade that's causing the problem.

I've tried surrounding sections with an autoreleasepool (as I've had that issue before releasing memory on non-UI threads when doing video processing) but that didn't make a difference.

I've also tried forcing the faces Vector to release its memory, but again to no avail.

Does anyone have any ideas?

```
- (bool)detectAndDisplay :(Mat)frame
{
BOOL bFaceFound = false;

vector<cv::Rect> faces;
Mat frame_gray;

cvtColor(frame, frame_gray, CV_BGRA2GRAY);
equalizeHist(frame_gray, frame_gray);

// the following line leaks 5Mb of memory per second
face_cascade.detectMultiScale(frame_gray, faces, 1.1, 2, 0 | CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, cv::Size(100, 100));

for(unsigned int i = 0; i < faces.size(); ++i)
  {
  rectangle(frame, cv::Point(faces[i].x, faces[i].y),
            cv::Point(faces[i].x + faces[i].width, faces[i].y + faces[i].height),
            cv::Scalar(0,255,255));
  bFaceFound = true;
  }

return bFaceFound;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you actually have a leak? If it leaks 4-5Mb/sec I imagine it should crash pretty quickly.

Comment: Without the face detector the app is stable in memory and runs indefinitely, when I turn on this section it will run for about a minute or so before I get memory warnings and an eventual exit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using the same source code as you, suffering from exactly same problem - memory leakage. The only differences are: I use Qt5 for Windows and I am loading separate .jpg images (thousands of them actually). I have tried same techniques to prevent the crashes, but in vain. I wonder whether you already solved the problem?

The similar issue is described [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/FaceDetection) (bold paragraph, at the real bottom of the page), however this is write-up for the previous version of OpenCV interface. Author says:

> The above code (function detect and draw) has a serious memory leak when run in an infinite for loop for real time face detection.

My humble guess is, the leakage is caused by badly handled resources inside `detectMultiScale()` method. I did not check it out yet, but `cvHaarDetectObjects()` method explained [here](http://www.cognotics.com/opencv/servo_2007_series/part_2/page_2.html), might be a better solution (however using an old version of OpenCV is probably not the best idea).

Combined with a suggestion from previous link (add this line at the end of operations: `cvReleaseMemStorage(&storage)`), the leakage should be plugged.

Writing this post made me want to try this out, so I will let you know as soon as I know whether this works or not.

---

**EDIT :** My guess was probably **wrong**. Try to simply clear 'faces' vector after every detection instead of releasing it's memory. I am running the script now for quite a piece of time, few hundreds of faces detected, still no sign of problems.

---

**EDIT 2 :** Yep, this is it. **Just add `faces.clean()` after every detection.** Everything will work just fine. Cheers.

Comment: Maybe you should submit this as a bug (and suggest the correction) to opencv devs ( http://code.opencv.org ). Or you can do your own git pull request, instructions or somewhere on that page.